# LefHand p4000 cluster - volume

Tags: vmware-vsphere, lefthand, hp

what is the best practice to create volumes to manage sql servers, file servers and web servers - all are in VM ? i am also planing a remote site with replication on selected volumes.

Please give your inputs - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

HP has a couple of documents that I would highly recommend.  We configured our systems using these guides with excellent results.

The first one is building high-performance/high-availability IP storage networks:
http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01750150/c01750150.pdf

The second one is for SQL configuration with HP P4000 SANs:
http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01750912/c01750912.pdf

Comment: Chris S. is absolutely right. Passthrough LUNs are critical for performance. Additionally, make sure that your SQL log disk uses full provisioning and that you use 64k block size when formatting the data and log disks.  I think these are in the guide, but wanted to elaborate just in case...

Answer (score 2):

Quick rule of thumb. If you need maximum performance then use a passthrough LUN for every HD.

Usually this isn't the case. For SQL servers it is, use passthrough LUNs only. For everything else you can usually pile the VHDs together on a single LUN. It will depend on your cluster and SAN environment however; especially for replication and hypervisor software.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put as few VMs on a LUN/datastore as possible (depending on your situation).
2. Typically your web servers are not going to be high disk IO, so they can live with either the SQL servers or the file servers.
3. A lot of this depends on what kind of IO you are going to be pushing.
4. Always follow the software vendor's best practices for setting up the applications.